# When importing a Mandrill class it gives me a AttributeError

Tags: python, mandrill

So I'm using Mandrill to send out emails and when I use it through the python interpreter it works fine but when I go to a higher directory and try to import it, it gives me a AttributeError:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "server.py", line 5, in
>   
>       fetch()   File "/home/kousha/projects/test/app.py", line 108, in fetch
>       send.SendEmail(x, i, "test")   File "/home/kousha/projects/test/mandrill/send.py", line 5,
>   in SendEmail
>       client = mandrill.Mandrill('apikey') AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Mandrill'

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Also the hierarchy is like this:

```
app.py
server.py
mandrill(folder)
__init__.py(inside mandrill folder)
send.py(inside mandrill folder)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is most likely attributed to the fact that you created a module named mandrill, but yet you are trying to reference another by the exact same name. I suggest you change the name of your module to something else to not break the reference to the proper module.

Comment: Hi sorry, I forgot to add that but its already in the file. (Its empty though)

Comment: Ah ok. I have a feeling that the fact that you have named your module mandrill, it is clashing with the actual module you want to use. Can you try renaming it to something else, make the necessary reference changes and try again?

Comment: thanks @idjaw. By changing the folder name and editing the references, it worked.